# I am a British citizen and I want to move to Ireland with my Thai wife

Tags: visa, uk-citizens, ireland, thai-citizens

Currently, I live and work in Turkey with my Thai wife. I would like to move to Ireland with my wife. Is it hard to get a visa, how long does it take to get a visa and can we apply for the visa in Turkey or does my wife need to fly back to Thailand?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a visa; your wife does.

The  Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service 
has quite a good [website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-long-family-eueea).

The visa she is looking for is a short-stay 90 day C-visa.  See [this page](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Family%20Members%20of%20EU_EEA%20_Swiss%20citizens).  That page doesn't give a timescale, but does say applications are "accelerated"; the normal C-visa page says "prepare your application three months before you travel" - so it should probably be less than three months (and might be a *lot* faster).

To live permanently in Ireland, she will need to apply for a "Residence card of a family member of an EU citizen" within those 90 days.

She can apply for a visa from the country where you are legally resident (which I assume will be Turkey in her case).